# RavenDB: Raven Query not returning correct count with document authorization

Tags: statistics, authorization, ravendb, where-clause

```
  public class EngineInfo 
  {
    public int Id{get;set;}

    public int? AircraftId { get; set; }

    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }

    public string RegNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

// Here is the code which uses the above model. I have 17,000 documents with this model

```
       ravenSession.Store(new AuthorizationUser
        {
            Id = "Authorization/Users/1",
            Name = "user-1",
            Permissions =
                            {
                                new OperationPermission
                                    {
                                        Allow = true,
                                        Operation = "EngineInfos/View",
                                        Tags = "Company/100"
                                    }
                            }
        });

 1. var query = ravenSession.Query<EngineInfo>();
```

// When I log query.Count(), I see all the documents count ie., 17000, This is ignoring the  authorization I set in the before statement. If I add where clause to the above statement it is working and I could see the correct count. But I want to get all the documents for which the user has authorization to.

```
 2. var query = ravenSession.Query<EngineInfo>().ToList();
```

Now, I get the correct count considering authorization. But the problem is unless I mention Take(x), it will not return all the results.
I tried with

```
   RavenQueryStatistics queryStats;
    query.Statistics(out queryStats); 


   queryStats.TotalResults
```

I still could not get the authorizes results. I get all the count.

Could you please help me figuring out in finding TotalCount of the query results without loading all records?

My requirement is to display all engines in an searchable ExtJS paging grid. I need to know the total count of the records to display calculate and display the number of pages(page count is fixed).

Comment: Do you get the right counts if you take [skipped results](http://ravendb.net/docs/faq/skipped-results) into account?  See also [paging with skipped results](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/paging)

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, see http://ravendb.net/docs/intro/safe-by-default.

`session.Query<Post>().Count()` will give you the count of all the posts on the server, while  `session.Query<Post>().ToList().Count()` will give the count of the posts that was fetched to the client.

By default, RavenDB apply .Take(128) to the query, in order to encourage you to do paging and be safe by default. If you want to get more then that you need to specify how much to take, like `.Take(1024)`, but by default the server will not return more then 1024 items at once. You can configure the server to do so, but this is not recommended. You much better use paging as the user cannot handle that much on info at once anyway.

Comment: Thanks Fitzchak. I agree. But Authorization is not applying on the command session.Query<Post>().Count(). When I set authorization for a particular user, it is expected to calculate the count of all the documents for which authorization satisfies, instead I get all the documents count in the database with that model.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is that Raven's QueryStatistics ignore the Authorization bundle. This [has been reported in the Raven Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/YrEulS6xwP8).

As far as I can tell, there isn't, at the time of this writing, a reliable way to get the total count of authorized documents for a query. It seems to me that the Authorization bundle should include some support for this.

I'll look into it and update this answer as I find out more.

Comment: Any news on getting count of authorized documents?