# RavenDB Authorization Bundle proper user of SecureFor

Tags: authorization, ravendb

I am attempting to use RavenDB's authorization bundle to limit the results of a query (on WorkItems) by the permissions that have been explicitly set on WorkItem documents.

For example:

I have a user bob@bob.com with a userId of /users/1 and a WorkItem that has the following permissions set in the Meta-Data:

```
"Raven-Document-Authorization": {
    "Tags": [],
    "Permissions": [
      {
        "Operation": "/Operations/WorkItem/Search",
        "User": "users/1",
        "Role": null,
        "Allow": true,
        "Priority": 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

I would then expect the following code to limit a query (from Bob's perspective) to this one WorkItem, because that is all he has permission to.

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    session.SecureFor("raven/authorization/users/1", "/Operations/WorkItem/Search");

    var workItemsQuery = from wi in session.Query<WorkItem>()
                     select wi;

    var debts = workItemsQuery.ToList();

    // do something with the work items
}
```

I based my code on the following example from RavenDB's documentation (Context & User section): http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/server/extending/bundles/authorization-bundle-design

What I am getting instead is WorkItems that have no explicit permissions set.  This is very puzzling to me because if I run the following code:

```
using (var session = mDocumentStore.OpenSession())
    {
       var answer = session.Advanced.IsOperationAllowedOnDocument(userId, operation, securableId);
       var allowed = answer.IsAllowed;
    }
```

allowed is true.

One additional item of note, I am attempting to ignore or simply not use the authorization bundle's concept of role and I wonder if this is having some unintended effect.

It is very possible that I am misunderstanding their example, could anyone shed any light on this subject for me?  Thanks in advance.

Also, I wondered if the issue I am encountering was related to this StackOverflow question: [RavenDB: Raven Query not returning correct count with document authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357057/ravendb-raven-query-not-returning-correct-count-with-document-authorization), but their issue seems to be with the count and not necessarily the actual results.

Comment: It appears that the issue was related to the use of "raven/authorization/users/1" syntax.  When I changed the search command to simply use, "users/1" it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to tiddy up this question, I will provide an answer to what was causing my problem.  The issue was related to the use of "raven/authorization/users/1" syntax. When I changed the search command to simply use, "users/1" it worked correctly.