# How to speed up Raven DB query performance?

Tags: c#, ravendb

Could anyone help me speed this query up? I'm using RavenDB 3.5.8 and the following query is taking quite some time (this is exceptionally true on first load):

```
var query = session
                .Query<Card>()
                .Include(p => p.AuthorId)
                .Include(p => p.CompanyId)
                .Where(x => !x.Id.StartsWith("Archived"))
                .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);

do
{
    var popStash = stashedResults != null && stashedResults.Count > 0;
    if (popStash)
    {
        stashSkip = stashedResults.Count;
    }

    results = query
        .Statistics(out stats)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ModifiedAt)
        .Skip(this.ServerPage * this.ServerPageSize)
        .Take(this.ServerPageSize)
        .Select(MapCard)
        .Where(x => x.IsAuthorized)
        .Skip(clientPage * command.PageSize)
        .Take(command.PageSize - stashSkip)
        .ToList();

    if (popStash)
    {
        results = results.Union(stashedResults).ToList();
        stashedResults.Clear();
    }

    if (results.Count < command.PageSize)
    {
        ++this.ServerPage;
        clientPage = 0;

        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            stashedResults = results;
        }
    }
    

} while (results.Count < command.PageSize &&
    stats.TotalResults >= (this.ServerPage * this.ServerPageSize) + this.ServerPageSize);
```

I know it's far from perfect, but note that the double `Skip` and `Take` is necessary due to the fact that RavenDB doesn't support authentication by default, so I have to `Map` each card and add the `IsAuthorized` field to it with the following code snippet:

```
IsAuthorized = session.Advanced.IsOperationAllowedOnDocument("Authorization/Users/" + user.Id, "Cards/View", card.Id).IsAllowed;
```

Basically what happens is that first the query loads a bunch of cards (actually ServerPageSize defines the number of cards there) without considering security and later when security is applied `command.PageSize` card is loaded. (The webpage dynamically loads the cards - first 50 cards are loaded and after these are viewed another 50 is being grabbed and so on..).

Can someone please gve me hints how to boost the performance of my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the *streaming* support in order to avoid multiple queries.

You are also querying on a negative, it is far better to query on something positive and then negate.

Note that this means that you are running an enormously expensive SELECT N+1, for each result, you'll get a query.

Why aren't you using the authorization bundle query filtering feature?

See the documentation here:

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/server/bundles/authorization#operations

You are missing the call to `SecureFor`

You can use:

```
session.SecureFor("Authorization/Users/" + user.Id, "Cards/View");
```

Now RavenDB will do the filtering server side.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot use the authorization bundle and paging simultaneously. RavenDB encourages you to use paging. This is why there is the Statistics mechanism, which gives back the total count. So far ok. But when you want to get the statistics (total count) it will skip authorization. 
See the following links:
- https://groups.google.com/g/ravendb/c/YrEulS6xwP8
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357057/ravendb-raven-query-not-returning-correct-count-with-document-authorization

Comment: Why the total number of items is unknown, the queries will work and filter the irrelevant data.

Comment: Yes, filter, but NOT CONSIDERING AUTHORIZATION. That's my main issue.

Comment: You cannot do both, I'm afraid. In general, you can avoid showing total number of items in authorized queries.

Comment: I was afraid that I can't do so. And based on my experience I think I also cannot say to ravenDB that I want the next 50 documents, for which I have the right to see. So authorization only can be applied after the document is loaded (session.SecureFor doesn't seem to work in this case).